# Effective way to connect SQL from dump to mobile app backend web application in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

So I recently started learning about google cloud platform. And I am currently trying to figure out how to connect a backend to a database and be able to perform REST actions from a small application I am working on. I have been able to do this successfully on heroku, however I am trying to transfer my knowledge from heroku and apply it in google cloud, but it is proving difficult. I have been able to upload the application successfully and I have added the sqldump as a database to the project also on the cloud. But when I try the REST services using postman, it returns the 404 page. Now, the application is built with hibernate and being a mobile app backend, there is only the index page with the available API restpoints which should query the database. This application works perfect on my localhost and has worked with heroku and I have been able to set this all up using the resources provided by google but I may have skipped a resource to make this work. If anyone could please give me an idea, or share resources that could help, or point me in the right direction, that would be really helpful.